# Can not read Mifare Classic cards through NFC in Android 5.1

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, nfc, rfid, mifare

I am working with NFC to read Mifare Classic 1K cards.

The code is working for all Android devices for Android 5.0 and below versions but when I tested my code on devices with Android 5.1, it does not work.

I have tested my code on Nexus 7 (4.4, 5.0), Nexus 5 (5.0), Sony Xperia, and Samsung devices and it was working very fine.

But when Android upgraded from 5.0 to 5.1, in some of the new devices (Nexus 6, Moto x Play) my program does not work.

My code,

```
MifareClassic mfc = MifareClassic.get(tagFromIntent);
```

returns `null` when I scan my card in Android 5.1 otherwise in versions below 5.1 it works fine.

#### Code:

```
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
public String AuthenticateCard(Context context, Intent nfcIntent) {
    String blockData = null;

    //Get an instance of the TAG from the NfcAdapter
    Tag tagFromIntent = nfcIntent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    String idFromIntent = ByteArrayToHexString(tagFromIntent.getId());

    Log.v("onNewIntent()", "NfcAdapter TAG : " + tagFromIntent
            + "NfcAdapter ID : " + idFromIntent);

    Log.v("onNewIntent()", "TAG TYPE : " + tagFromIntent.describeContents());

    //Get an instance of the Mifare classic card from this TAG intent

    //It works successfully with android 5.0 or below versions but returns null in devices with android 5.1.
    MifareClassic mfc = MifareClassic.get(tagFromIntent);


    try {
        // Connect to card
        mfc.connect();
         // authenticate the sector
        if (mfc.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(MY_SECTOR, MY_KEY)) {

            for (int k = 0; k < 1; ++k) {
                int block = mfc.sectorToBlock(MY_SECTOR) + k;
                byte[] data = null;

                try {
                     // Read the block
                    data = mfc.readBlock(block);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("IOException", "\n" + "Block " + block
                            + " data: " + e.getMessage());
                    continue;
                }
                 // Convert the data into a string from Hex format.
                blockData = ByteArrayToHexString(data);

                // reading first 8 bytes only
                blockData = blockData.substring(0, 8);
            }

            if (blockData != null) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.served);
            } else {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.coins);
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.not_valid_rfid,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.professionals);
        }

        mfc.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.coins);
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.error_while_scanning,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.coins);
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.error_while_scanning,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }finally {
        try {
            if (mfc != null)
                mfc.close();
            if (mp != null)
                mp.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return blockData;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem that you experience is likely not related to the upgrade to Android 5.1. Instead, obtaining an instance of the `MifareClassic` object for a tag will only work on platforms that support MIFARE Classic. Hence,

```
MifareClassic.get(tagFromIntent)
```

will return `null` on platforms that do not support MIFARE Classic. This essentially means that your app will only work on devices with an NFC chipset from NXP.

- For the Nexus 7, only the 2012 version will support MIFARE Classic. The 2013 version (Broadcom chip) will not be able to read MIFARE Classic.
- The Nexus 5 will not be able to read data from MIFARE Classic.
- Most (all?) Sony Xperia should work fine.
- The Samsung Galaxy S4 (and possibly the Note 3 and Note 4) will not be able to read data from MIFARE Classic. The S3 and the S5 work fine though.
- The Nexus 6 has a Broadcom NFC chip and therefore cannot read data from MIFARE Classic.

Note that there is the system feature `com.nxp.mifare`, which should signal if a device supports MIFARE Classic (see [ThomasRS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459579/thomasrs)'s answer) . However, many vendors did not bother to properly configure this. Consequently, using

```
if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("com.nxp.mifare")) { ... }
```

is not a very reliable way of identifying devices that support MIFARE Classic.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

Some NFC chips do not support Mifare Classic cards. See this [hasMifareClassic()](https://github.com/skjolber/ndef-tools-for-android/blob/master/ndeftools-util/src/org/ndeftools/util/activity/NfcDetectorActivity.java) method.

Comment: Thanks. You It helped Me alot. :)